# Delete wishlist product is not working Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I am trying to delete wishlist items , using the below function
but i am not getting anywishlist product using the below function,

code -

```
    <?php

/**
 * A Magento 2 module named Hp/Wishlist
 *  
 */

namespace Hp\Wishlist\Model;

use Hp\Wishlist\Api\WishlistManagementInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProvider;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation as AppEmulation;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface;



/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the WishlistManagementInterface
 */
class WishlistManagement implements WishlistManagementInterface
{

      /**
     * @var WishlistProviderInterface
     */
    protected $wishlistProvider;
    private $wishlist;
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var CustomerRegistry
     */
    protected $_wishlistFactory;
    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    private $_objectManager;

    protected $_productload;
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storemanagerinterface;
    protected $customerRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanagerinterface,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $_wishlistCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist

    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->wishlist                   = $wishlist;
        $this->_productloader             = $_productloader;
        $this->_wishlistFactory           = $wishlistFactory;
        $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
        $this->storemanagerinterface      = $storemanagerinterface;
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer's name by Customer ID and return greeting message.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException If customer with the specified ID does not exist.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */

    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {

        if ($productId == null) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid product, Please select a valid product'));
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
        try {
            $wishlist = $this->_wishlistFactory->create();
            $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
            $wishlist->addNewItem($productId);
            $wishlist->save();
            return 'Product with sku - ' . $product->getSku() . ' is added to wishlist';
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId)
    {
        if (empty($customerId) || !isset($customerId) || $customerId == "") {
            throw new InputException(__('Id required'));
        } else {

            $collection =
                $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId)->getData();
            $wishlistData = [];
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $productInfo = $this->_productloader->create()->load($item['product_id']);

                $data = [
                    "wishlist_item_id" => $item['wishlist_item_id'],
                    "wishlist_id"      => $item['wishlist_id'],
                    "product_id"       => $item['product_id'],
                    "store_id"         => $item['store_id'],
                    "added_at"         => $item['added_at'],
                    "description"      => $item['description'],
                    "qty"              => round($item['qty']),
                    "product"          => $productInfo,
                ];

                $wishlistData[] = $data;
            }
            return $wishlistData;
        }
    }

    public function removeWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $item = $this->_objectManager->create(Item::class)->load($productId);
        $wishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist($item->getWishlistId());
        $item->delete();
            $wishlist->save();

        return 'is removed from wishlist'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the module code that your are using, is the method removeWishlistForCustomer get called?

Comment: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`wishlist`, CONSTRAINT `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `wishlist` (`updated_at`) VALUES ('2020-06-25 10:57:32') {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 23000): Report ID: webapi-5ef4831d07df5;

Comment: please print the customer id and product id

Answer (score 0):

**1.please create your own controller and Test**

```
<?php

protected $wishlistModel;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlistModel
) {
    $this->wishlistModel = $wishlistModel;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customerId = 1;
    $productId = 6;
    $wish = $this->wishlistModel->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
    $items = $wish->getItemCollection();

    /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
            $item->delete();
            $wish->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Comment: i have tried this its not working

Comment: $items = $wish->getItemCollection();
This returns null

Comment: maybe customer id is null please check

Comment: which model used to get current customer-id

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: i have added code

Comment: \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
i used

Comment: have you checked the customer id using the echo statement, please check first

Comment: Yes i had just used static customer id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109830/discussion-between-rasik-miyani-and-developer).